# passing integer value from one UIView to another UIview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiview

I am creating a code in which i want to pass integer value for one uiview to another view.In another uiview that integer value so as text of label.How make code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this in .h file in SecondViewController

```
int value;
```

Make below function in SecondViewController

```
-(void)setValue:(int)number{
    value=number;
}
```

Now In First view controller do like this:

```
ParentViewController *objSecond = [[ParentViewController] initwithNibName:@"parentView.xib" bundle:nil];

[objSecond setValue:15]; // Pass actual Value here
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecond animated:YES];
[objSecond release];
```

Now, In secondViewController viewWillAppear Method write this.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
      myValue = value;
}
```

Please check spelling mistakes as I hand written this. Hope this help.

If you are not using navigationContoller then you can do something like this.

```
SecondViewControler *objSecond = [[SecondViewController] initwithNibName:@"secondview.xib" bundle:nil];
[objSecond setValue:15]; // Pass actual Value here
[objSecond viewWillAppear:YES];
[self.view addSubview:objSecond];
[objSecond release];
```

Answer (score 0):

declare a varable in .h file

```
NSInteger tempValue;
```

declare a method like that:

```
- (void)SetValue:(NSInteger)value {
    tempValue=value;
}

- (void)GetValue{
   return tempValue;
}
```

when you set it, you use:

```
AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[app SetValue:xxxx]
```

when you need it, use:

```
AppDelegate* app = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
xxxx = [app GetValue];
```

Comment: i don't have any idea about that. can u expand in details.above function where i use in 1st or 2nd view.

Comment: they are in one viewcontroller or two.

Comment: in my project i have one app delegate file six view.

Comment: I have changed the answer , u can have a try

Comment: (void)GetValue(){ return tempValue; } so error expected '{' before '(' token

Comment: sorry for the '()',just delete it

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as integer value itself as u do in c or in any other language.
In the second view, u can convert it to string with [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",intVal];

In second view, declare a NSUInteger variable , say NSUInteger _intVal.

In .h file, declare a method like

```
-(void)setIntVal:(NSUInteger)inVal;
```

In .m file,

```
-(void)setIntVal:(NSUInteger)inVal
{
   _intVal = inVal;
}
```

Now u can use the _intVal in the second view.

Answer (score 0):

When you are going from view1 to view2 then do like this.

Take one variable in view2 and set the property as

```
@property (nonatomic,readwrite) int val;  //this is in the view2 .h file
```

in view2 .m file do this.  `@synthesize val;`

Then when you are adding the view2 as subview to view1 then

```
view2object.val=someval;// like 1,2,3....
```