# Want to pass integer value to the another view

Tags: iphone, xcode4, nsinteger

I am creating an iphone app in which i have some vale in integer in my oneviewcontroller and i want that integer value in my secondviewcontroller controller.

value will be random.
I stored this integer value in **id score**

Nw I am using this code but,i cant get integer value.

CODE : [passing integer value from one UIView to another UIview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622586/passing-integer-value-from-one-uiview-to-another-uiview)

Integer Value always becomes zero at the secondviewcontroller.
Any Help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

MY CODE:

FirstView.h file

```
NSInteger myScore;  
id score;  
NSInteger totalscore;
```

.m file

```
NSInteger *cal = (myScore * 100)/400  ;

        totalscore = cal;
        score = totalscore;
```

SecondView.h file

```
 int scorevalue ;
```

SecondView.m file

```
FirstViewController *firstVC = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
value = firstVC.Score;
NSLog(@"SCORE : %d" ,value );
```

Comment: @Sascha : I edited my code.. have a look please..

Comment: @Shrey : Ok.. I tried this but i want that value in SecondView.. and in secondview the value becomes 0(ZERO)..  Any help..!!:o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

If I need to store the int value 4 in FirstViewController,

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:4 forKey:@"integer"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

I can get the get in the SecondViewController as,

```
int value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"integer"]
NSLog(@"integer = %d", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"integer"]);
```

Hope it will work perfectly.

Comment: Ohh... Yes , It works just fine..
Thanks a lot Developer.. :) I was working on it from last 2 days..
Again thanks for help..!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Since 'id' denotes objects ([see ref](http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html#idtype)) , but we require data type.

Instead of declaring it as `id`, declare it as `int` itself.

Something like,

```
int score;
```

or

```
NSInteger score;
```

**Edit:**

Also add the property and synthesize it.
In .h

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) NSInteger score;
```

In .m

```
@synthesize score;
```

In the first view controller, pass the value to the secondView by,

```
NSInteger *cal = (myScore * 100)/400  ;
totalscore = cal;
score = totalscore;
secondViewObj.score = score;
```

Comment: I tried this but don't know how to get that value in my secondView.. This is the main problem i am trying to solve..

Comment: Ya.. I tried that but still value becomes 0(Zero)
then i tried Developer's answer.. and it works fine..  I got my solution :) Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

A simply way is, store the value in the NSUserDefault and get the value of the integer from NSUserDefault in secondviewcontroller.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.. But I am new to iPhone development.
So can you please tell me how to store value in NSUserDefault?
do you have any link or document for that??

Comment: Will send you in the next answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take this in .h file in SecondViewController

```
int value;
```

Make below function in SecondViewController

```
-(void)setValue:(int)number{
    value=number;
}
```

Now In First view controller do like this:

```
ParentViewController *objSecond = [[ParentViewController] initwithNibName:@"parentView.xib" bundle:nil];

[objSecond setValue:15]; // Pass actual Value here
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecond animated:YES];
[objSecond release];
```

Now, In secondViewController viewWillAppear Method write this.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
      myValue = value;
}
```

Please check spelling mistakes as I hand written this. Hope this help.

If you are not using navigationContoller then you can do something like this.

```
SecondViewControler *objSecond = [[SecondViewController] initwithNibName:@"secondview.xib" bundle:nil];
[objSecond setValue:15]; // Pass actual Value here
[objSecond viewWillAppear:YES];
[self.view addSubview:objSecond];
[objSecond release];
```